# Magento EE 2.2.2 move store from one multi site instance to another multi site instance

Tags: multistore, store-view, migration

What would be the easiest way to move a store from one multi site instance to another multi site instance on Magento EE 2.2.2?

Need to move store settings, products, product attributes, content blocks, etc, not worried about customers and orders.

Comment: use advanced export extension

Comment: Is there one you would recommend that works on Magento Enterprise?

Comment: Do you want to transfer data only from one to another store?
I am not getting your requirement.

Comment: On one instance I have 12 stores and the other instance I have 2 stores.  I need to move one store from the instance with 12 stores to the instance with 2 stores.  If I can get customers and order moved with it great but it is not absolutely required.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157435)

Comment: I don't want to move data from one store to another store, I want to move the entire store (all data) from one install of Magento to a different install of Magento.  Both are on the same server and both are running the same version of Magento.  Same theme, same code, same everything.